# JavaScript accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, object-oriented

I'm trying to refactor some code I wrote months ago when I used to use lots of anonymous functions. The way I'm trying to do it now is by taking all those functions and rewrite them within Object Literal Pattern.

I'm new to this kind of pattern and I would like to know if I'm doing it right, what should I improve or if there's a better way to write the code for easier maintainability.

The first piece of code I refactored is in the following rows and is about an accordion view.

I've also created a [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x6g12r0w/2/) for this where you can see the whole code including the former way of writing the js.

```
var mainAccordion = {
  init: function() {
    this.cacheDom();
    this.bindEvents();
  },

  cacheDom: function() {
    this.$elTrigger = $('.js-accordion-trigger');
  },

  bindEvents: function() {
    this.$elTrigger.on('click', this.elExpand);
  },

  elExpand: function(event) {
    var $el = $(this),
        $elContent = $el.next('.accordion__content'),
        $elParent = $el.closest('li'),
        $elSiblings = $el.parent().siblings(),
        $groupSiblings = $el.parents('.list-with-header').siblings();

    if (!$elParent.hasClass('is-expanded')) {
      event.preventDefault();

      $elContent.show();
      $elParent.addClass('is-expanded');

      $elSiblings.removeClass('is-expanded');
      $elSiblings.find('.accordion__content').hide();

      if ($groupSiblings.find('li').hasClass('is-expanded')) {
        $groupSiblings.find('li').removeClass('is-expanded');
        $groupSiblings.find('.accordion__content').hide();
      }

      // animate accordion element to top of page
      $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $elParent.offset().top
      });
    } else {
      event.preventDefault();

      $elContent.slideUp('fast');
      $elParent.removeClass('is-expanded');
    }
  }
};

mainAccordion.init();
```

Answer (score 2):

Some small changes I'd recommend listed below:

**D.R.Y.**

Why don't you call `event.preventDefault` before your control statement since it will be called in both the `if` and the `else` case?

**Avoid doubling up on lookups**

I am not very experienced in jQuery, but can't you make some `if` checks not double up on lookups?

```
var liGroup = $groupSiblings.find('li')
if (liGroup.hasClass('is-expanded')) {
     liGroup.removeClass('is-expanded');
```

Also check the specs on `removeClass()`..perhaps you can call `removeClass()` without checking `hasClass`?

**Formatting/Readability**

Your code is difficult to read without more formatting. For example, it's not clear which `if` matches up with the `else` from skimming the code. It shouldn't be necessary for a reader to parse parens/brackets to figure out what the `if...else` pairing is.

Also a few more comments would be helpful. For example, comments describing your control statement branching in a few words would be welcome.

Comment: You could simply do `$groupSiblings.find('li.is-expanded').removeClass('is-expanded')` instead of that `if` (and `var`) :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ thanks for confirming, had just added an edit to my own answer asking about that.